# RenderBox was not laid out stack

Tags: flutter, dart

Hello this is my error:

RenderBox was not laid out: RenderFlex#b7b0f relayoutBoundary=up1 NEEDS-PAINT
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1940 pos 12: 'hasSize'

This is my code:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    return Scaffold(
      body: FutureBuilder(
          future: createListOfMatches(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            return Row(
              children: [match()],
            );
          }),
      floatingActionButton:
          FloatingActionButton(child: Text('next'), onPressed: () => next()),
    );
  }

match() {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        Positioned(
            top: top,
            left: left,
            child: Draggable(
              data: 10,
              onDragUpdate: (details) {
                top = top + details.delta.dy;
                left = left + details.delta.dx;
                print('$top, $left');
                setState(() {});
              },
              child: Material(
                  child: Container(
                      height: 50, width: 50, child: Image.asset('match.jpg'))),
              feedback: Material(
                  child: Container(
                      height: 50, width: 50, child: Image.asset('match.jpg'))),
            )),
      ],
    );
  }
```

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

In the flutter documentation there are a few common failures:

there is also [‘RenderBox was not laid out’"](https://docs.flutter.dev/testing/common-errors#renderbox-was-not-laid-out)

> While this error is pretty common, it’s often a side effect of a
> primary error occurring earlier in the rendering pipeline.
>
> What does the error look like?
>
> The message shown by the error looks like this:
>
> content_copy RenderBox was not laid out:  **RenderViewport#5a477
> NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE**
>
> How might you run into this error?
>
> Usually, the issue is related to violation of box constraints, and it
> needs to be solved by providing more information to Flutter about how
> you’d like to constrain the widgets in question. You can learn more
> about how constraints work in Flutter on the page [Understanding
> constraints](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/layout/constraints).
>
> The RenderBox was not laid out error is often caused by one of two
> other errors:
>
> ‘Vertical viewport was given unbounded height’ ‘An
> InputDecorator…cannot have an unbounded width’

I hope this could help you a little.